# Creating user account in CMD/PowerShell for current logged in user

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

We have over 100 users that need to be made users on their Windows 7 machines. It's very easy to write a script using `net user`, but it doesn't get us a level of automation we need. I would like to be able to detect the current logged in user and fill that into the `net user`.

It can be an autodetect of the %username% or we could have each user enter information in a dialog input box. I have found examples of these, but I am not an expert in batch so creating the link between the input data to `net user` is unclear to me. Is there someone who can fill in these gaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, what you mean, the `net`  command also depends strongly on local/regional language settings. What you can try:

```
net user "%username%" "%userdomain%"
```

```
net user "%username%" "%logonserver%"
```

Please see also `net /?` and `net user /?`.

Comment: Excellent. I have no idea why I didn't just try using the wildcard.